# How to ensure that all phantomjs drivers are shut down?

Tags: selenium, browser, selenium-webdriver, automation, phantomjs

Basically I've created a program using selenium webdriver (phantomjs) and if errors occur I gracefully close the drivers so no unwanted processes are hanging behind the scenes.

My concern though, is what would happen if my program got shut down for some reason (either by the user or the system). The remaining driver processes would hang behind infinitely which could raise some serious issues in the long run.

Is there any way to ensure that whenever I start my program, any existing phantomjs processes will get shut down (or even better, shut them down whenever the program is shut down)?

I'm using selenium webdriver using C# by the way.

Comment: I wonder why GhostDriver doesn't exit PhantomJS whenever there was no communication between the client and the driver for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:
$ killall phantomjs

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/191